# Laravel getting value of checkbox in ajax Error :Cannot read property 'checked' of null

Tags: ajax, checkbox, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am showing the checkbox value checked or unchecked based on the db value.but when user try to change it like unchecked it and update the value. i call the ajax i getting this error.

Thanx for help
Code

```
 <div class="{{count($employees) !=0 ? 'sidebar-hide': 'sidebar-customize'}}">
        <a>
          {{ Form::checkbox('Employee','1',$user->employee) }}
           <i class="fa fa-id-card"></i> 
            <span>Employee</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Below is the Ajax Function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#customize').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      var customers=document.getElementById('customers').checked ? '1' :'0' ;
      var accounts=document.getElementById('accounts').checked ? '1' :'0';
      var Inventory=document.getElementById('InventoryItems').checked ? '1' :'0';
      var Employee=document.getElementsByName('Employee').checked ? '1' :'0'; 
       console.log(Employee);

       $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

       $.ajax({
           url :"{{ url('user')}}",
           type :'POST',
           data :{

              customer : customers,
              accounts : accounts,
              inventory: Inventory,
              employee : Employee
           },
           dataType: 'JSON'
         //   ,
         // success: function( data ) {
         //    $("#ajaxResponse").append(data.msg);
         //    console.log(data);
        //}  

       });   
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its like i have to include the Id from the checkbox

```
{{ Form::checkbox('Employee', 'Employee', $user->employee, ['id' => 'employee']) }}
```

Ajax Code :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

       $('#customize').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var employee=document.getElementById('employee').checked ? '1' :'0' ;
           console.log(employee);
       });


    });
```

Works prefectly fine as aspected

Answer (score 0):

Is the HTML created dynamically?

If so, then you need to bind the event to a parent element and use the jQuery.on() method instead of click()

```
$('#parentelement').on('click', 'div.sidebar-customize', function(e) {
  //code
});
```

The second parameter of the method needs to target the element you're trying to use. From you HTML, I can't tell what that will end up being. Maybe implement an additional class or ID so the HTML can be targeted better.

Comment: HTML is not generated dynamically.

Comment: Code call ajax
               <input type="submit" value="customize" name="customize sidebar" id="customize" class="btn btn-success">
             </div>

Comment: what does div.sidebar-customize means sidebar-customize is a css class

Comment: Well, from what I can tell, you're not actually targeting anything. For example, I don't see any HTML element with an ID of 'customers'